# Can we create multiple tableau data extract (.tde) within one data source?

Tags: report, tableau-api

I am newbie in Tableau. I am using Tableau desktop version 9.3. I want to know whether we can create multiple tableau data extract on a single data source. As I have data of last 5 years and I want to create tde for every single year (eg. tde for year 2011, tde for year 2012).
Is it possible to create different tableau data extracts on single data source in tableau desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create as many extracts as you like. Do it from the sheet as opposed to the data window. Right click the data source name and choose extract. Name and save as you wish. You'll then have 5 distinct data sources.

One caveat, you'll have a better experience if you save the data source as well, not just the extract. The data source has all the metadata information in the data pane (aliases, formulas, default formats, groups etc). The extract has a copy of the data only.

The command to save a data source is "Add to Saved Data Sources". You will have the option of saving just the datasource as a TDS file or packaging your extract with the datasource as a TDSX file.

Tableau will let you save an extract and then just open that extract as a data source, known as a naked extract, but you will lose most of the metadata and the connection to the original data.

If you have Tableau Server, you can publish your datasources instead of saving them as files.

Comment: Hello Alex,                                                                                                                          Thanks for the response. I have data of last 5 years from 2011 to 2015. I have to generate report on that complete data. I am thinking to create 5 tde for 5 years in one data source to optimize performance. As old data from year 2011 to 2014 is not going to change (i.e. data is locked) so there is no need to refresh those tde (for years 2011 to 2014) which will save my time of refreshing tde.

Comment: For year 2015 I am planning to create tde and apply incremental update and weekly full update on it. So in spite of refreshing entire data (which includes data for all 5 years or 5 tde ) I'll refresh only data for year 2015 which in turn will save the time required to refresh data source and optimize the performance of tableau.